# Terraform - no matching Route53Zone found

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to deploy a NextJS app via Terraform however I can't seem to get the Route53 Zone to work. I have registered the domain via Route53 and have setup a hosted zone with that very domain. When using the CLI command `aws route53 list-hosted-zones` I can successfully see the hosted zone there. However whenever trying to run `terraform plan` I'm met with this issue:

```
Error: no matching Route53Zone found

  on .terraform/modules/aws_static_site/main.tf line 1, in data "aws_route53_zone" "zone":
   1: data "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
```

Here is my tf file:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  profile = "rozzle-static-site"
}

module "aws_static_site" {
  source  = "dvargas92495/static-site/aws"
  version = "1.2.0"

  domain = "rozzle.co.uk"
  secret = "REMOVED"
  tags = {
    Application = "rozzle-static-site"
  }
}

provider "github" {
  owner = "dvargas92495"
}

resource "github_actions_secret" "deploy_aws_access_key" {
  repository      = "static-site-demo"
  secret_name     = "DEPLOY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
  plaintext_value = module.aws_static_site.deploy-id
}

resource "github_actions_secret" "deploy_aws_access_secret" {
  repository      = "static-site-demo"
  secret_name     = "DEPLOY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
  plaintext_value = module.aws_static_site.deploy-secret
}
```

I can't figure out how this works. Hoping someone can help!

Comment: What does your data block look like?

Comment: What data block? The data block in the module?

Comment: Correct, the error is referencing a data block, what does that data block look like and any associated inputs it is using.

Comment: ```data "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
    name  = "${local.zone_domain_name}."
    private_zone = false
}
```

Comment: The zone_domain_name local: ```zone_domain_name = join(".", slice(local.domain_parts, local.domain_length - 2, local.domain_length))```

Comment: I looked into the module source a bit. Do you have var.domain set anywhere, or are you hard-coding the `domain` input? Try to set `domain = var.domain` and also set the default value of `var.domain` to `rozzle.co.uk`.

Comment: Also could you update with what `local.domain_parts` and `local.domain_length` are expecting as inputs?

Comment: I'm hard coding the domain in my aws.tf file.

`domain_parts = split(".", var.domain)
domain_length = length(local.domain_parts)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the aws-static-site module. On line 22 of the module's main.tf, it does this:

```
zone_domain_names = {
      for d in local.all_domains: d => join(".", slice(split(".", d), length(split(".", d)) - 2, length(split(".", d))))
}
```

And in your case it produces this:

```
local.zone_domain_names = {
  "rozzle.co.uk" = "co.uk"
  "www.rozzle.co.uk" = "co.uk"
}
```

Which it tries to use for the zone data block.

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
    for_each = toset(values(local.zone_domain_names))
    name     = "${each.value}."
}
```

This naturally fails, as you do not control the "co.uk" domain.

It appears that this module only handles second level domains, not third level domains. I would suggest opening a bug report for this module.

---

Also, as a quick and dirty fix, you can download the aws-static-site code and create a local module from the aws-static-site and modify the code to work only for third level domains by changing the number 2 to number 3 on line 23 of the main.tf:

```
zone_domain_names = {
      for d in local.all_domains: d => join(".", slice(split(".", d), length(split(".", d)) - 3, length(split(".", d))))
}
```

NB. This local module will then only work for third level domains, not second level domains.

Comment: Thanks! So this was indeed an issue. Another issue that I had got myself into is that my hosted zone nameservers were different to what was in the Route53 Domain. Updating this also helped solved a few issues.